# Characters repeat when starting SSH in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to access a box via PuTTY SSH. Once I log in, every character I type is duplicated, as in *dduupplliiccaatteedd*.

What setting do I need to change to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

Reconfigure your putty session to turn off local echo.

[image: putty local echo]